# converting for loop to foreach

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

How can we convert this kind of **for** loop to **foreach** loop in php?

```
$integerPartOfAverage = 4;
for($counter = 0; $counter < $integerPartOfAverage; ++$counter) {
    $stars[] = 'Yellow';
}
```

Comment: There isn't an object or array to loop through, so it's difficult to see how you could

Comment: yes, that's why raise the query...If any ways @ADyson

Comment: This does not really make sense. The only sense of that loop is to repeat the array assignment 4 times. That is what a `for` loop is for. A `foreach` loop is for something else, it is to loop over _something_ that can be iterated over.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, I'm aware of this concepts...but some force on me to convert all `for` loops to `foreach`. So finding some good ways

Comment: _This does not make any sense, sorry._

Comment: `some force on me`...people often force others to do things which don't make sense. Often this is because the person would not otherwise do that thing...due to it not making sense. :-)

Comment: @ADyson By taking positive approach, the ways open now for replacing the for loop.  Here we have beautiful 2 answers now...also it would help other community developers.

Comment: Yes but one doesn't use a loop, and the other confects an array to loop through. So the first isn't really what you asked for, and the second just makes the code more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not really make sense. The only sense of that loop is to repeat the array assignment 4 times. That is what a `for` loop is for. A `foreach` loop is for something else, it is to loop over *something* that can be iterated over.

Instead what you could do is get rid of the loop completely and directly setup the target array:

```
<?php
$stars = array_fill(0, 4, 'Yellow');
print_r($stars);
```

The output is exactly the same as what your loop creates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Yellow
    [1] => Yellow
    [2] => Yellow
    [3] => Yellow
)
```